# Solving another bessel equation by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

For a problem solving class I need to find the general solution of ODE $x^2y''+(\frac{3}{16}+x)y=0$ in terms of $J_{\nu}$ and $J_{-\nu}$, if possible. $\nu$ represents the Bessel parameter.

A hint is given, namely that useful substitutions would be $y=2u \sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{x}=z$; this should lead to the ODE being reduced to a Bessel equation. Substituting this value and applying the chain rule leads to the ODE $z^2u''+zu'+(4z^2-(\frac{1}{4})^2)u=0$, which almost has the form of a Bessel equation with $\nu=\frac{1}{4}$, apart from the coefficient 4 in front of the $z^2$ in the $u$ coefficient.

*What is the proper way of solving this ODE by reduction to a Bessel equation?*
*Can this be done?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you will get $J_{1/4}(2z)$ and $Y_{1/4}(2z)$. To see this, try to put $s=2z$ and $v(s)=u(z)$. The terms with derivatives will behave very nicely:
$$
zu'(z)=sv'(s)\quad\text{and}\quad z^2u''(z)=s^2v''(s).
$$
Are you sure of the original differential equation? It yields simpler solutions, as Jack mentions.

**Update**

Your original differential equation transforms into
$$
z^2u''(z)+zu'(z)+(4z^2-(1/2)^2)u(z)=0.
$$
Note the $(1/2)^2$, and not $(1/4)^2$.

The same idea as before gives $J_{1/2}(2z)$ and $Y_{1/2}(2z)$. Now, these functions can be simplified into cosines and sines with some square roots of $x$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you. About the original ODE: it was, like I stated, supposed to be solved in terms of Bessel functions.

Comment: See my edit. There seem to be a small error in your differential equation for $u$.

Comment: Aha that's what you meant by the original ODE, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

By setting $$ y(x) = x^{1/4}\, f(\sqrt{x}) $$
the original ODE boils down to the ordinary differential equation:
$$ f''(x) + 4\,f(x) = 0. $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question states that the general solution should be expressed as Bessel functions.

Answer (score 0):

The previous remark answers your question, keeping track of the expansions
\begin{gather*}
\cos z = J_0(z)-2J_2(z)+2J_4(z)-\cdots;\\
\sin z= 2J_1(z)-2J_3(z)+\cdots.
\end{gather*}